# how to test and debug IOS Flutter app on Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, flutter

I'm making app for IOS with Flutter but I'm on Windows. How can I test and debug my app on Windows? Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to test it directly from Windows. To build and test an iOS app you have to have a Mac.

Nonetheless, there are workarounds. For example, you could use a tool like Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI) to build and test iOS apps on Windows.

Install the tool from the website: https://www.odevio.com

Configure Odevio to work with your Apple Developer Account : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html

And then you can either start a build in Configuration to access your remote Mac and configure XCode or test your app in the iOS simulator.

Or build an IPA to test on your local device with an Ad Hoc build type.

Comment: Alright thankss man